# Why does my output vary when sending lists over a TCP socket in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, list, sockets, server, client

Could someone please explain why my socket program outputs the message in a strange way everytime I run the code.

I am supposed to receive the server results from a list sent from the client as follows:

> Sending request 'E1.0 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1'
>
> Received response:
>
> Sending request 'S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-15'
>
> Received response:
>
> ...

Instead, I get this:

> Sending request 'E1.0 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1'
>
> Received response:
>
> Sending request 'S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-15'
>
> Received response:
>
> Sending request 'G4.1 0 0'Received response: XIncorrect command type
>
> Sending request '4 1 0'
>
> Received response: XIncorrect command type
>
> Sending request 'E1.0'
>
> Received response:
>
> Sending request 'S1.0'Received response:
>
> Sending request 'S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 -1e-15'Received response:
>
> Sending request 'Not a number'Received response: XIncorrect command type

This happens all the time, sometimes it works as it should most time the received data is out of place. This is my code...

server.py

```
import socket
port = 12345
mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.bind(('localhost', port))
mySocket.listen(0)
clientsocket, addr = mySocket.accept()
print("Connection from: {}\n".format(str(addr)))

while True:
    encoded_message = clientsocket.recv(2048)
    data = encoded_message.decode()
    print(data)
    if not data:
        break
    else:
        acknowledge = "Sending request \'{}\'".format(data)
        clientsocket.sendall(acknowledge.encode())
        request_code = data[0]
        if request_code == 'E':
            messageO = "Received response: \n\r"
            clientsocket.sendall(messageO.encode())
        elif request_code == 'S':
            messageO = "Received response: \n\r"
            clientsocket.sendall(messageO.encode())
        else:
            messageO = "Received response: XIncorrect command type\n\r"
            clientsocket.sendall(messageO.encode())

clientsocket.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
host = 'localhost'
port = 12345

mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host, port))

testing_strings = ["E1.0 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1",
                   "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-15",
                   "G4.1 0 0",
                   "4 1 0",
                   "E1.0",
                   "S1.0",
                   "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 -1e-15",
                   "Not a number",
                   "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 0",
                   "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 G 1 1e-15"]

count = 0
print(len(testing_strings))
count = 0
for l in testing_strings:
    if count == (len(testing_strings)-1):
        mySocket.send(l.encode())
        data = mySocket.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
        mySocket.shutdown(1)
    else:
        mySocket.send(l.encode())
        data = mySocket.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
        count += 1

mySocket.close()
```

Comment: Your problem is the line breaks?

Comment: i think you problem is that for each iteration you send 2 messages from the server but only `recv` once in the client. that is why you get some grouped up replies

Comment: Ok, ill try to see what i can do